# Reducing resolution of an Image in VisualBrush

Tags: wpf, printing

In WPF, I am creating 100s of VisualBrushes, one for each page in a FixedDocument (each containing a canvas with this VisualBrush as Background), which is then sent to the printer.

The printer cannot seem to handle this large FixedDocument, running out of memory. So, I am wondering if there is a way to reduce the resolution of the images in these VisualBrush to ease the load on the printer.

I don't see any API in VisualBrush to do this. Any one has any ideas on this?

Comment: Did you try using ImageBrush instead of VisualBrush?

Comment: Hi, no, because I have to print a large portion of my visual tree into the VisualBrush(es). There is no way to print visual tree content into ImageBrush (in order to get a low resolution image), is there?

Comment: You might perhaps render the root of your visual tree into a RenderTargetBitmap with low resolution. With 48 DPI (i.e. half of the standard 96) you could use a bitmap with half the width and height of the actual viewport size.